# iOS - Sending authentication to FOSUserBundle Database not working but cURL works

Tags: php, ios, symfony, curl, afnetworking

I have a table managed by FOSUserBundle with users in it in a Symfony2 application. I am able to access routes protected by a firewall with cURL without any problems. Let's say I have a route /api/something that is protected and I wanted to access it with cURL, I used:

```
   curl -v -u paul  http://example/web/app_dev.php/api/something/
```

The above works no problem. However, from my app, it always returned a 401: You are not authenticatedd when I use the following snippet below. I converted it to base 64 since AFNetworking says it has to be in that format. What am I missing??

```
    NSData *pass = [@"somestring" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64pass = [pass base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSData *user = [@"anotherstring" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64user = [user1 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:base64user password:base64pass];
```

Here is the HTTP Header returned and AFNetworking is not setting the headers. How can I accomplish this task?

```
{ status code: 401, headers {
    Allow = "GET, POST";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 31 Jan 2014 14:25:48 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Debug-Token" = c562ea;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'll set this on your code. Here is the catch. Since you have empty password, so make the `base64` of `paul:` like this way(remember the colon).

```
BASE_64 = base64 of "paul:"
```

Then set this http header.

```
Authorization: Basic BASE_64
```

Of course remove this one as your requesting the authorization through headers.

```
[self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:base64user password:base64pass];
```